# Capturing the selection of the currently selected cell

Tags: excel, vsto, selection, add-in

I'm developing an Excel Add-In (application level), with VSTO 2013 using VB.NET.

I'm using a nice project that emulates the [Excel's "refEdit" control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32805/RefEdit-Emulation-for-NET). With this control, the user can pick a range from the worksheet, through the SelectionChanged event.

My problem is: If the user selects a single cell, and then he starts the refEdit control (that minimizes the form) to pick a cell, he can't choose the currently selected cell, just because it doesn't fire the SelectionChanged event. To do it, he must select another cell (and then the refEdit is filled for the first time, with the new selection address) and then select the previously selected cell, to finally get its address into the control.

I didn't find any excellent workaround, only things like selecting another cell. If I had something like "Clear.Selection", it would be perfect, but I think it doesn't exists, right?

Any smart solution?

Answer (score 0):

If possible it is preferable to write code that runs when the refEdit is started to do whatever you need, without relying on the SelectionChange event.

Sheet events are not exposed in an obvious way, but you can use the following code to trigger the event:

```
Run "Sheet1.Worksheet_SelectionChange", Selection
```

`Selection` is provided as the Target argument for the event.

---

`Selection` might not be a `Range` though, so you should consider incorporating:

```
If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
```

Comment: Ok, I can run this Run command if I capture a user click into the currently selected cell, right? But how do I capture this event to force the SelectionChange? I still struck in this question...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. If you run my code as soon as the form is displayed, or the refEdit is clicked in, then it would fire the SelectionChange event, which is what you requested to happen?

Comment: No, because this will force the selection of the currently selected cell.
What I want is: the user can CLICK at the current selected cell AFTER the form is open, and this action fills the ref edit's text box. The problem is that the event that fires the box filling is the "selection change"... So, if he clicks at any cell after the form is open, it fills the box correctly, except for the cell that was selected when the form was open. If I do what you are suggesting, I will force the user's choice to the currently selected cell, but I want to let the user make this choice in the next click...